# Choosing keywords for a search engine

Tags: search-engine, keyword, google-ads-api

Given the fact that a search engine deals with a broad range of topics, to promote a new search engine with google adwords, how do you choose keywords?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: @JohnConde Where is it better suited in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having some Search Exclusive Keywords is a good idea.

Suppose the search engine is "Findforme". A website like this can have the keywords Find, Findforme and so on. Also, having some keywords like "Search Faster" or "Find Faster" should be able to help. Now almost all the time, a user will not look for another search engine in google as they are already satisfied with what google is providing them. Having various popular Search Term Queries (STQ's) as keywords in advertising for their search Engine may help in the ad popping up, although it may not have relevance to the user and the advertiser will end up paying a large cpc.

I searched some of the above listed keywords on google and these were the following results.

Search Faster: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Search+Faster&oq=Search+Faster&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.2701j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Hpoe this helps :)

Comment: "and the advertiser will end up paying a large cpc." As it is cost per click, doesn't that mean that you only pay if people click on it? So having thousands of keywords without anyone clicking on your ad because it's not relevant to them isn't such a bad idea or is it?

Comment: You are right when you say that we pay only when a user clicks on the ad. But the thing is, when there are several keywords that arent being clicked, they will have a very low quality score. Low quality score means lesser visibility of the ad as well as a high cpc. So whenever (if ever) the ad gets visible and gets clicked, the company will have to pay a large cost for that click. It may not be getting many clicks, but the cost will be very large and will result in unnecessary spends.